# Your application is being uploaded?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, application-loader

I am uploading application using xcode 5 but its taking too much time to authenticate to itune store.

[image]

I also tried using Application Loader.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes time usually, if it's taking too much maybe the servers are saturated. Just try later.

Answer (score 0):

This is why because your app contain more space otherwise you have less internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a long time on a slow upload connection (~5 Kb/s) - it would just time out every time after 20 minutes or so.  Once I went on a faster upstream connection the issue immediately resolved.